# "Appdriver" like Webdriver for android apps

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, automation, android-testing

I was looking for an automation **framework similar to selenium webdriver** for android that would have **these features**:

1. Allow finding elements on the UI, just as the webdriver allows by xpath,id etc..
2. Emulating user actions like keystrokes,page scroll,clicks and other touch events.
3. All these **without** having the source code of the app. We have a lot of testing frameworks which allow us to do these, but it should allow us to work with any, or atleast most android apps without having their source code.
4. These scenarios should be written in preferably java or atleast should support integration with java libs so that we can do tasks such as read excel sheet using POI and copy texts in those and paste the content to say the EditText in successive iterations.

I could not find a framework that would suit my needs so kindly suggest the same.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. That being said, you seem to be describing `uiautomator`.

Comment: @CommonsWare this is a clear question related to Android testing. I'm asking to suggest a proper testing framework for automating it without source code which u won't find many on the web. Infact, I couldn't find ANY. So there is no QUESTION OF ANY OPINION.

Comment: "I'm asking to suggest a proper testing framework" -- and that is off-topic for Stack Overflow, as is asking for any sort of off-site resource. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for what is and is not on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm not sure of that.I hav seen many questions asking to suggest some framework etc.. BTW does such a framework exist that can automate third party apps without source code? I just have seen monkey runner, but its too poorly documented to use.

Answer (score 3):

We do test automation without having the source code of our customer apps and there definitely are framework that allows you to do that. You can typically check Robotium that should do what you expect.

Comment: Yes it looks like what I want. Mostly because we write tests in Robotium using java! I have upvoted for this as of now. Would mark as answer soon. Thanks man!!